# retrieve fixed length subsequence in strings centered around a given position

Tags: r, substring

In R I have a nx2 data frame where first column is a character vector (protein sequence) and second column a numeric  vector specifying a position in the character vector, e.g.:

```
test <- data.frame(SEQ = c("LLKTISPAR", "KLKKRGVTTVK", "PAVLPTGGGLGTGTV"), 
                   POS = c(4,5,13))
```

I would like to retrieve the subsequence of a given size centered by the POS vector, which I managed to do with the function:

```
pep.windows <- function(x, n){
    ifelse(!is.numeric(x[[2]]) | x[[2]] < n +1 | n+x[[2]] > nchar(as.character(x[[1]])) ,
           NA, 
           substring(x[[1]], x[[2]]-n, x[[2]]+n)) 
}
```

Using the function to get windows 1 and 4 characters on each side of the POS character gives:

```
pep.windows(test, 1) 
[1] "KTI" "KRG" "TGT"
```

and

```
pep.windows(test, 4) 
[1] NA          "KLKKRGVTT" NA
```

My problem is that in the second example I want to make the function (say pep.windows2) return "X" for each position outside the window range, it would return:

```
> pep.windows2(test, 4)
[1] "XLKTISPA" "KLKKRGVTT" "GLGTGTVXX"
```

I cannot make this work. Would be nice to have it as a function that I could use apply on (something like `apply(test, 1, pep.windows2, ...)` ) - tried, couldnt make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with:

```
pep.windows <- function(x, n) {
  get.buffer <- function(num) paste(rep("X", num), collapse="")
  left.text <- sapply(pmax(0, n-x$POS+1), get.buffer)
  right.text <- sapply(pmax(0, x$POS + n - nchar(as.character(x$SEQ))), get.buffer)
  paste0(left.text, substring(as.character(x$SEQ), x$POS-n, x$POS+n), right.text)
}

pep.windows(test, 1)
# [1] "KTI" "KRG" "TGT"
pep.windows(test, 4)
# [1] "XLLKTISPA" "KLKKRGVTT" "GLGTGTVXX"
```

We define a function `get.buffer`, which inputs the number of replications of X needed, and we build the left and right buffers of the appropriate size before putting it all together.